# Messed up permissions-->blank pages for phpMyAdmin and postfixadmin

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, phpmyadmin, webserver

I just wanted to fix the permission issue I originally had and made things much worse. I wanted to make sure the permissions of my WWW directory are set in a way that I can edit files with my user account. So I followed instructions I found [here](http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache).

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/USER/www 
chmod go-rwx /home/USER/www
chmod go+x /home/USER/www
chgrp -R www-data /home/USER/www
chmod -R go-rwx /home/USER/www
chmod -R g+rx /home/USER/www
chmod -R g+rwx /home/USER/www
```

So after this I checked and editing files with my regular user account worked. but then I found out that `postfixadmin` and `phpmyadmin` are both returning a blank page. Oops :( I assume it is because of the permission changes i applied recursively on the WWW directory :-/

The nginx error.log says:

```
From 2015/07/25 14:49:38 [error] 15383#15383: *35438 "/home/USER/www/domain.xom/public_html/postfixadmin/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 123.45.678.90, server: , request: "GET /postfixadmin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

*How can i figure out which user I need to grant privileges on what files?*

I did the following
chmod o+x -R /home/USER/www/domain.com

But it did not make a difference.

The current permissions for the directories are

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   21 Jan 20  2015 chaosql -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
drw-rw-r-x 17 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 21  2015 postfixadmin
```

Those directories are in /home/USER/www/domain.com/public_html

edit:
it's weird. even if i recursively apply 777 permissions on the postfixadmin directory it shows a blank page and in the log there's another entry like the one mentioned above. shouldn't that give all users permission to read?

Comment: Hi, did you fix this?